# Logical Statement Determining if the intersection between two agentsets is empty

Tags: netlogo

I have seen on here how to create an intersection or union of two agentsets, but I am trying to say if any turtle in agentset a is in agentset b, return true. I was trying

```
ifelse (member? (one-of my-intersections) destination-intersections)
```

but I am pretty sure this is just testing if one element in my-intersections is in destination -intersections instead of testing every element. Is there some way to use a for each? Or is there another functionality I am unaware of?

Again, I have already referenced

[NetLogo two agentsets operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425518/netlogo-two-agentsets-operations)

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to write such a test is:

```
to-report test [ as bs ]
  report any? as with [ member? self bs ]
end
```

To try it:

```
create-turtles 5
show test (turtle-set turtle 0 turtle 1 turtle 2) (turtle-set turtle 3 turtle 4)
show test (turtle-set turtle 0 turtle 1 turtle 2) (turtle-set turtle 0 turtle 3 turtle 4)
```

will show:

```
observer: false
observer: true
```

<s>It's not the most efficient way, however, because the `with` clause builds an intermediate agentset that's not really needed.</s>

A faster test would be:

```
to-report test [ as bs ]
  let result false
  ask as [
    if member? self bs [ 
      set result true
      stop
    ]
  ]
  report result
end
```

**Edit:**

I spoke too fast. As per [the NetLogo wiki page on compiler architecture](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Compiler-architecture#optimizer), the combination of `any?` and `with` **does** get optimized to exit early. Bottom line: you should use the first version (i.e., `any? as with [ member? self bs ]`).