# NetLogo3D : Detecting a turtle between two radius

Tags: netlogo, area, flock, boids

I'm currently modeling some simple boids using Netlogo3d and i'm having an issue with the in-cone and in-radius functions.

(I'm re-implementing the article 'Collective Memory and Spatial Sorting in Animal Groups' from Couzin, Krause, James, Ruxton and Franks)

i use three different area around my boids to define its behaviour :
One for repulsion, one for attraction and one for orientation.
Thoses three are sphere around the boid
[Thoses areas look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViuDY.png)
I'm detecting turtles in thoses area like this :

```
to find-flockmates-repulsion  ;; turtle procedure
  set flockmatesRepulsion other turtles in-cone (visionRepulsion * scale) fov
end
to find-flockmates-orientation  ;; turtle procedure
  set flockmatesOrientation other turtles in-cone ((visionOrientation + visionRepulsion) * scale) fov
end
to find-flockmates-attraction  ;; turtle procedure a modifier pour enlever les turtles dans le radius visionOrientation
  set flockmatesAttraction other turtles in-cone ((visionAttraction + visionOrientation + visionRepulsion) * scale) fov
end
```

But those three areas are overlapping and i don't want them to overlap.

Is there a way to reduce the selection of the in-cone and in-radius function like :

```
set flockmatesAttraction other turtles [ (in-cone ((visionAttraction + visionOrientation + visionRepulsion) * scale) fov) and not (in-cone ((visionOrientation + visionRepulsion) * scale) fov) ]
```

And if possible not with a loop on 2 lists, I'm trying to make my boids efficient
Thank you!

(PS : Sorry for the broken english)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than finding a modification of in-cone, which I'd think is written to be efficient,  you might simply compute your three agent sets as you did in the question, and then remove the smaller agent-set from the larger one to get the difference agent-set, which is what you are after.

So you'd do this:

```
to find-flockmates-repulsion  ;; turtle procedure
  set flockmatesRepulsion other turtles in-cone (visionRepulsion * scale) fov
end
to find-flockmates-orientation  ;; turtle procedure
  set flockmatesOrientation other turtles in-cone ((visionOrientation + visionRepulsion) * scale) fov
end
to find-flockmates-attraction  ;; turtle procedure a modifier pour enlever les turtles dans le radius visionOrientation
  set flockmatesAttraction other turtles in-cone ((visionAttraction + visionOrientation + visionRepulsion) * scale) fov
end

;; and then remove the overlap using the member? reporter
set flockmatesAttraction flockmatesAttraction with [not member? self flockmatesOrientation ]
```

By the way I used the answer that Charles posted of how to subtract one agent set from another 
[Removing an agentset from another agentset (the agents from the first set which are also present in the second set)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47840347/removing-an-agentset-from-another-agentset-the-agents-from-the-first-set-which) in which he said:

> I think what you want is the member? primitive. If D and B are
>   agentsets, the following should give you the members of D that are not
>   members of B.
>
> let DminusB D with [not member? self B]

Comment: Thank you!It worked great without adding too much calculation time